Identifying this chip marked 1200 378 AKEP

Chip is marked 1200 378 AKEP.
It seems that four pins are unsoldered, this could be the root cause of board stucking, but I don't know which is this chip to understand if those unsoldered pins could generate the board problem.

It's a Texas Instruments TPS51200 DDR termination regulator. That being said, it's very unlikely that the thermal pad isn't soldered. The excess solder probably just got sucked under the IC and thus isn't as visible as on the other pads.


(Source: aliexpress.com)
